# animation CSS3+jquery

Tags: jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/8953ob8g/

I am a bit confused why the animation doesn't occur BOTH whenever I reveal/close the menu but only when I reveal it? I'd really love to hear some tips regarding the issue, thank you very much in advance for any sort of reply.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>projekt powazny</title>
    <!--external style-sheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <!--external scripts, jquery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/39b504251e.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--header with nav-->
    <header>
      <!--menu-->
      <div id="menu-click">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <!--menu-hidden + add class show on click-->
      <div id="menu-hidden">
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>

body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #233D4D;
}

#menu-click {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}

#menu-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FE7F2D;
  width: 200px;
}

.open {
  animation: slide-in 300ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-click").click(function() {
    $("#menu-hidden").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `transition` instead of `animation`, it is more suitable for this kind of task

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-click").click(function() {
    $("#menu-hidden").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #233D4D;
}

#menu-click {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}

#menu-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FE7F2D;
  width: 200px;
  transition: left 300ms ease;
}

#menu-hidden.open {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/39b504251e.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
      <!--menu-->
      <div id="menu-click">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

      <!--menu-hidden + add class show on click-->
      <div id="menu-hidden">

      </div>
      
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining CSS3 and jQuery to animate class transitions seems like it may be prone to error.  I would highly recommend using jQuery UI's animated `toggleClass()`.

```js
$("#menu-click").click(function () {
  $(".menu-hidden").toggleClass("open", 500);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #233D4D;
}

#menu-click {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}

.menu-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FE7F2D;
  width: 200px;
}

.open {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/39b504251e.js"></script>
<!--menu-->
<div id="menu-click">
  <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<!--menu-hidden + add class show on click-->
<div class="menu-hidden">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only animating the reveal (with slide-in). To fix:

```
$(function() {
    var $menuClick = $('#menu-click'),
        $menuHidden = $('#menu-hidden');

  $menuClick.off('click').on('click', function() {
      if ($menuHidden.hasClass('initial')) {
          $menuHidden.removeClass('initial').addClass('open');
      } else if ($menuHidden.hasClass('open')) {
        $menuHidden.removeClass('open').addClass('close');
      } else {
        $menuHidden.removeClass('close').addClass('open');
      }
  });
});
```

And in your css:

```
body {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #233D4D;
}

#menu-click {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}

#menu-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FE7F2D;
  width: 200px;
}

.open {
  animation: slide-in 300ms ease forwards;
}

.close {
  animation: slide-out 300ms ease backwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
```